# Finding a sequence with RecurrenceTable

Tags: recursion, sequence

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Q: How can the following recursion equations be solved using `RecurrenceTable`?
>
> $\qquad a_{2n}=2\,a_n-1,\, a_{2\,n+1}=2\,a_n+1,\, a_{1}=1$

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[2 n] == 2 a[n] - 1 , a[2 n + 1] == 2 a[n] + 1, a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 15, 1}]
```

But...

Comment: You should attempt to explain your issue if possible, rather than leave people to guess what the "But.." refers to. In the documentation for `RecurrenceTable` it says that the equations must be in the form of `a[n + i]` where `i` is any fixed integer. Based on that, I would guess that your problem cannot be defined using `RecurrenceTable`. Idk if this helps, but you could define the relation like this: `a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := If[EvenQ[n], 2 a[n/2] - 1, 2 a[(n - 1)/2] + 1]` and that will at least get you the values for each n value.

Comment: Do you have to use the command `RecurrenceTable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the built-in function `RecurrenceTable` can handle the kind of recurrence you present in this question. However, the problem is amenable to the approach I discussed in [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190318/3066).

First, observe that the recurrence relation is really a matter of odd and even numbrs; i.e., it is defined one way for odd numbers and only slightly differently for even ones.

Second, write a recursive function based on this observation. Like so:

```
Clear[a]
a[1] = 1;
a[n_?EvenQ] := 2 a[n/2] - 1
a[n_?OddQ] := 2 a[Floor[n/2]] + 1
```

Now, it is possible to generate a sequence to any specified length, say 63.

```
Table[a[i], {i, 63}]
```

> ```
> {1, 
>  1, 3, 
>  1, 3, 5, 7, 
>  1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 
>  1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 
>  1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 
>     33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63}
> ```